# Cross correlation: ValueError: object too deep for desired array

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, numpy, dataframe

I am trying to run a simple cross correlation.

```
np.correlate(C,C,"full")
```

I am getting the error: ValueError: object too deep for desired array

here is a preview of the variable output.(I have imported pandas as pd and numpy as np)

```
[IN]: type(C)
[OUT]: TypeProxy: <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>

[IN]: C

[OUT]: # lines below
DataFrame:
Equity(24 [AAPL])
2010-12-20 00:00:00+00:00 0.600
2010-12-21 00:00:00+00:00 1.210
2010-12-22 00:00:00+00:00 0.890
```

I know this question has been asked before, multiple times, I have read the similar questions. I acknowledge that it inst a new question but I am begging for help I have spent hours trying to find out how to fix this.
In other solutions they mention the line:

```
numpy.digitize(df.iloc[:, 0], bins)
```

This gives me the error: NameError: name 'bins' is not defined

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

`np.correlate`expects two arrays as input while you seem to be providing matrices (see documentation: [np.correlate](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.correlate.html)).

You could transform your dataframe into a numpy array and compute the correlation column-by-column.